# How to reset token api in google mybusiness when expired?

Tags: google-my-business-api, google-business

In about 60 minutes, my token expired.
I searched a lot but couldn't find an answer.
I am using conjob to fetch api from google mybusiness.

Comment: Hi Linh! Did my answer solve your issue? If yes, please mark it as correct, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Tokens can be refreshed for offline access if you set the access type to "offline" during the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow build.

See:
https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder.html#setAccessType-java.lang.String-